# Devise. Create username automatically based on his email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Is it possible to created username based on his email automatically by using devise?

On register page, I have only email and password fields.

For example, when user create a new account with email `randomname@gmail.com`,
I'd like that his username automatically become a `randomname`. How can I accomplish it?

Comment: What are you going to do about randomname@gmail.com, randomname@yahoo.com, and randomname@random.com ?

Comment: I think it's fairly rare case for site with small audience and also, users are able to change their usernames after registration. Anyway, it better to be prepared, so I think I'll use callback to add some prefix like randomname2/3/etc for already taken usernames.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the firstpart of the email adress with a regex like `^[^@]+`, this will return everything from the start of the string before the `@` sign.

```
^ /* start of string or line */
[^@] /* character class capturing everything except @ */
+ /* match must happen atleast one time */
```

To add the username to your database, you can use a [callback](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html).

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :set_username

  private
    def set_username
      self.username = self.email[/^[^@]+/]
    end
end
```

Comment: What if there is someone we have hoobas@gmail.com and hoobas@yahoo.com how can I solve this conflict?

Answer (score 1):

To account for emails that have the same name but different urls you can add a random number at the end.

```
self.username = "#{self.email[/^[^@]+/]}-#{SecureRandom.hex(1)}"
```

This will return `hoobas-1f` an `hoobas-3c` to the two emails in the comment above.