# Rails with Devise: Set Unique Username from First Name

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

In my app I'm trying to automatically populate a `username` column from the `first_name` field that I already have tied in to my `Devise` login system.  In theory, it should just be the `user`'s `first_name` if they are the only one with that name, but it should be something like "Mal the 4th" or "Jayne the 3rd" if there are other `users` with that first name already.

So far, in googling and consulting other SO posts (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474355/devise-create-username-automatically-based-on-his-email) one) I have this basic structure in my `registrations_controller`:

```
  before_create :set_username

  private
  def set_username
    @users = User.where(first_name == self.first_name)
    same_first_name_array = []
    @users.each do |u|
      same_first_name_array << u.first_name
    end

    if same_first_name_array.size = 0
      self.username = first_name
    else
      self.username = first_name + " the " + ordinalize(same_first_name_array.size + 1)
    end
  end
```

But I'm struggling to fill in the blanks.  So far it looks like the best way to do it is to do an if statement that checks if that `first_name` is unique and, if it's not to `ordinalize` some kind of `count`, but please let me know if there's a better or "more Ruby" way.  Any help getting this to work would be appreciated!

Comment: why dont you add random strings to username, instead of specifiying which number of user it is

Comment: @opensource-ios the client requested it that way...

Comment: @opensource-ios, I added a possible solution to the OP.  Can you think of how to make it work given the new info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your way is correct, however can be optmized definately, you can avoid the step in which you create a array and populate all the same names.

Also, try to see if you can create a index on the first name column, this will optimise the query.

self.username already points to name user has entered, you need to change it only if it has multiple occurrences so no need of if / else. change it only if there are multiple occurrence.

You can rewrite it like below

```
    before_create :set_username

      private
      def set_username
        @users = User.where(first_name == self.first_name)
        self.username = @users.count.eql?(0) ? self.first_name : first_name + " the " + ordinalize(@users.count + 1)
      end
```

> Note: having user names likes this will create  performance issues when your application scales and has large number of users.

Comment: `first_name` and `username` are different columns, so I think that I still need an `if` statement for users with a unique first name, but the rest is much better.  Also, what did you mean about creating an index on the first name query?

Comment: i have updated the code, check if this works, instead of if/else, by index i meant a mysql index assuming MySQL is your DB